# É possível acessar o mesmo argumento duas vezes no sprintf?

Tags: php, string, argumento

No PHP tempos a função `sprintf`. Com ela podemos formatar os valores sequencialmente passados a partir do segundo parâmetro.

Por exemplo:

```
sprintf('Meu nome é %s e tenho %d anos de idade', 'Wallace', '26')
```

A saída será

> Meu nome é Wallace e tenho 26 anos de idade

Porém em um dado momento precisei de ter uma funcionalidade similar as que existem em linguagens como `Python` ou `C#`, onde você pode repetir na string de formatação um dos argumentos passados.

Por exemplo em Python

```
 s = "Meu nome eh {0}. Sim, o meu nome eh {0}. Eu tenho {1} anos de idade"
 s.format('Wallace', 1)
```

A saída seria:

> u"Meu nome é Wallace. Sim, o meu nome é Wallace. Eu tenho 1 anos de idade"

Observem que o parâmetro `"Wallace"` se repetiu sem a necessidade de passá-lo duas vezes.

Utilizando o `sprintf` do PHP, preciso de uma solução similar. É possível fazer a mesma operação do exemplo em Python em `PHP`, usando a função `sprintf`?

**Nota**: Gostaria de saber especificamente da função `sprintf`.Nesse caso, funções criadas pelo usuário não seria bem-vindas como resposta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Segundo a documentação da função [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php), você deve usar o caractere `$` antecedido por um número, que representa o número do argumento que você deseja capturar, e precedido pela flag de formatação desejada (por exemplo, `s`, `f` ou `d`).

A contagem dos argumentos começa a partir do número `1`. A expressão precisa ser inicializada por `%`, como todas outras formas usadas para formatar um argumento nas funções **sprintf**/**printf**.

Então, poderíamos escrever a string de formatação assim:

```
$tpl = 'Meu nome eh %1$s. Sim, o meu nome eh %1$s. Eu tenho %2$d anos de idade';

echo sprintf($tpl, 'Wallace', '26')
```

Lemos o código da seguinte maneira:

`%1$s` "Substitua esse token com o primeiro argumento (Wallace) e formate o mesmo como string.

`%2$d` "Substitua esse token com o segundo argumento (26) e formate o mesmo como inteiro.

[Exemplo funcional](https://ideone.com/WJU6rm)

Comment: Fiquei surpreso ao saber que no PHP tinha isso :D

Comment: E eu que ate tinha feito uma função para isso '-'

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Ninguém lê o manual! haha :P

Comment: @Laerte eu procuro no SO :D

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do [@laerte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139609/3635) está ótima e muito correta, mas resolvi deixar duas alternativas a resposta apenas pra tornar a escrita mais pratica dos *tokens*, se assemelhando ao [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) do Python:

### Sugestões 1:

Vou postar o exemplo que o [@Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241200/1518921) fez/postou esta função:

```
function format() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (count($args) == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (count($args) == 1) {
        return $args[0];
    }

    $str = array_shift($args);
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\{(0|[1-9]\\d*)\\}/', create_function('$match', '$args = '.var_export($args, true).'; return isset($args[$match[1]]) ? $args[$match[1]] : $match[0];'), $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Uso:

```
$str = 'Meu nome eh {0}.
        Sim, o meu nome eh {0}.
        Eu tenho {1} anos de idade.
        {0} {1} {1} {0}';

echo format($str, 'Wallace', 26);
```

### Sugestões 2:

Este eu criei agora, é basicamente o `vsprintf` mesclado com `preg_replace`

```
<?php
function format() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (empty($args)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (count($args) === 1) {
        return $args[0];
    }

    $str = array_shift($args);
    $str = preg_replace('#\{(\d+)\}#', '%$1\$s', $str);

    return vsprintf($str, $args);
}
```

Uso:

> O `{0}` não é suportado, então sempre inicia do `1`

```
$str = 'Meu nome eh {1}.
        Sim, o meu nome eh {1}.
        Eu tenho {2} anos de idade.
        {1} {2} {2} {1}';

echo format($str, 'Wallace', 26);
```

Exemplo online: http://ideone.com/0uf7cr

Comment: Lembra da minha que tinha debug_backtrace? :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert lembro sim, só não lembro os detalhes hehehe :D